# Positive Matrix Deflation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Hi suppose that I have a positive matrix $A$, if I use Hotelling Deflation, we have $$A' = A - \lambda_iv_iv_i^T.$$

Where, $\lambda_i$ is one of the eigenvalue of matrix A, and $v_i$ is its corresponding eigenvector. And the new matrix $A'$ will deactivate the corresponding eigenvalue of $v_i$ to 0. But the matrix $A'$ may not be positive matrix. So I just want to know whether there exists techniques that after the deflation process, I can still get a positive matrix or non-negative matrix.

**Clarify the problem**:

Suppose that we have a symmetric non-negative matrix $A$(the matrix is symmetric and all elements are non-negative), and the eigenvalues for $A$ are $\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,...,\lambda_n\}$(sorted as descending order). Now I need "deactivate" the largest eigenvalue, so I need to perform deflation on matrix $A$ for example Hotelling Deflation, then we have a new matrix $A'$ and the second largest eigenvalue for $A$ is now the largest eigenvalue for $A'$. But by performing Hotelling Deflation, $A'$ may not still be a non-negative matrix. So I just want to find out one deflation method, that can guarantee that the deflated matrix is still non-negative.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the matrix is $A$, not $M$..

Comment: It won't be positive definite, but it will be positive semidefinite.

Comment: Can you clarify what your objective is? It sounds like you are looking for a method by which one of the eigenvalues of the matrix is replaced with zero but the matrix remains positive definite. But this is impossible because a matrix with a zero eigenvalue cannot be positive definite.

Comment: The point of deflation is that you remove one eigenvalue from your matrix, so that the result is a direct sum of a smaller matrix and the zero matrix. Whether the smaller submatrix is still SPD is an interesting question.

Comment: Hi all, so I am looking for the deflation method that can have a output matrix that is positive matrix, that is all entries(elements) of the matrix are nonegative.

Comment: Hi all, I have modified the problem, please check it, thanks.

Comment: Please specify that $v_i$ has norm 1.

Answer (score 0):

See Schur's deflation described in the paper "Deflation Methods for Sparse PCA" by Lester Mackey (NIPS'08)